# How to edit $heading_title for Transactions in customer page in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have a site developed in Opencart.Now I want to edit the heading title of the Transaction page for customer account.I have looked into the code and found something like `$heading_title` for that page,but i am not able to find to make a change.Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change

```
<?php echo $heading_title; ?>
```

to

```
You custom title
```

But I believe that is part of template/language system and you should search for that variable's value.

Comment: Thanks [Mihai Iorga](http://stackoverflow.com/users/204701/mihai-iorga).Do you have any idea where can i find this variable.Thanks

Comment: I believe `/language/english/checkout/cart.php` ?